# Count number of line using C

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way to count the number of lines in my file using C?

Comment: **Editor's note:** This edit is a guess based on the OP's terrible English; the other possible interpretation of the question is: 'How can I count the number of lines of code in a C source file'. I believe the edit reflects the body of the question, while the other version reflects the title of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform this programmatically, open the file in text mode and perform fgetc() operation until you reach end of file. Keep a count of number of times fgetc was called.

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.txt");
    int ch;
    int count=0;
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(ch == '\n') count++;   
    } while( ch != EOF );    

    printf("Total number of lines %d\n",count);
```

Comment: If the file contains lines that are longer than 10000 characters, this will give the wrong answer. It would be better to just read character by character with getc, and count the newlines.

Comment: +1 @Thomas is right. It would be even better to read chunks of, say, 1024 bytes and loop over that buffer.

Comment: The new version, with fgetc instead of fgets, is better, but still not entirely correct: ch should be an int, not a char.

Comment: @Santiago: Reading in chunks will complicate the code, but one should probably not expect a big improvement in speed. The stdio library will buffer automatically, so the low-level reads will be done in chunks anyway.

Comment: @Thomas: Unless the file contains data with ASCII value greater than 127, char will fulfill the requirements. Of course it's true that fgetc will return int and not char type.

Comment: @Gunner – `char` might be unsigned, `EOF` might be −256.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the line number *within* your c source, most compilers support the `__LINE__` macro.
If you want to count line numbers of arbitrary text files *in* c, the following functions should be starting points:

- fopen() to open a file for reading
- fgets() to read lines
- eof() to check for end of file
- fclose() to close the file

Combining these into a line counter is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the `wc` command.  Most linux distributions include it.

Answer (score 0):

Please think for a moment about what you have to do to count lines in a file:

1. Open the file for reading, maybe with fopen( );
2. Read each line, one line at a time, maybe with fread( );
3. Increment a line counter that you've initialized to zero earlier;
4. Whwn end-of-file is returned from the next read of the file, you are done. printf( ) the line counter.

Answer (score 0):

One nagging issue that can effect the number of lines returned regardless of the method you use is whether the file contains a POSIX compliant `'\n'` at the end of the last line. There are a number of editors (and programs) that happily write the final amount of text to a file without the POSIX end-of-line. You can handle either case regardless of which method you use to determine the number of lines in a file.

If you are trying to determine the number of line in a *large* file, then you will definitely want a buffered read (e.g. reading multiple characters into a buffer, per-read) rather than a *character-by-character* approach. The can greatly improve the efficiency.

Putting those two pieces together, you can use either `fgets` or POSIX `getline` to determine the number of lines in a file fairly efficiently. For example with `getline` (which handles the line-end issue or you), you could do:

```
/** open and read each line in 'fn' returning the number of lines */
size_t nlinesgl (char *fn)
{
    if (!fn) return 0;

    size_t lines = 0, n = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, "r");

    if (!fp) return 0;

    while (getline (&buf, &n, fp) != -1) lines++;

    fclose (fp);
    free (buf);

    return lines;
}
```

With `fgets`, testing for additional text after the final *newline* is up to you, e.g.

```
/** note; when reading with fgets, you must allow multiple reads until
 *  '\n' is encountered, but you must protect against a non-POSIX line
 *  end with no '\n' or your count will be short by 1-line. the 'noeol'
 *  flag accounts for text without a '\n' as the last line in the file.
 */
size_t nlines (char *fn)
{
    if (!fn) return 0;

    size_t n = 0, noeol = 0;
    char buf[FILENAME_MAX] = "";
    FILE *fp = fopen (fn, "r");

    if (!fp) return 0;

    while (fgets (buf, FILENAME_MAX, fp)) {
        noeol = 0;
        if (!strchr (buf, '\n')) {
            noeol = 1;  /* noeol flag for last line */
            continue;
        }
        n++;
    }
    if (noeol) n++;     /* check if noeol, add 1 */

    fclose (fp);

    return n;
}
```

(*note:* you can add your own code to handle a `fopen` failure in each function.)