# Count the number of lines of a file in windows C

Tags: c

I have this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPCTSTR filePath = argv[1];
    DWORD numLines = _ttoi(argv[2]);

    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFile(filePath,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,NULL);


    DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(fileHandle, NULL);

    TCHAR* file =  (TCHAR*)malloc(fileSize);
    DWORD bytesRead=0;

    ReadFile(fileHandle,file,fileSize,&bytesRead,NULL);

    DWORD numLinesFile = 0;
    for(DWORD i = 0;i<fileSize;i++)
        if(file[i] == '\n')
            numLinesFile++;



    free(file);
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

which returns 0 every time, even though the file is actually 10 lines long.

Comment: should `fileSize` be instead `Size`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139213/count-number-of-line-using-c

Comment: By `returns 0` you mean `numLinesFile` is 0 at the end?

Comment: There's no reason to delete your code once your question is answered. You should leave it up in case some future programmer has the same problem you had.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(file)` is size of the pointer variable `file`. You want to pass `Size` to `ReadFile`

You may want to also explicitly use `char` instead of `TCHAR` - If you compile this with `UNICODE` defined it will not work, you're accessing unallocated memory.

Comment: Thanks, that was a bug, but there is still another bug left. Its still returning 2....

Comment: Your posted code is extracted from your real code - you're using the variable `fileSize` which isn't defined in your post.

Comment: @rad2 you did not. This code is incomplete. And there is still the `Size` vs `fileSize` issue.

Comment: @rad2: Now change `TCHAR* file` to `char* file`

Comment: Is your file utf-16 or utf-8/ascii?

Comment: Treating a utf-16 file as utf-8 will only overestimate the number of linebreakes, and never underestimate.

Comment: Where do you print numLinesFile?

Comment: I dont, I look at the debugger.

Comment: Print it. The debugger can be unreliable, especially in release builds.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(file)` that part is wrong. You want to put `Size` in there. `sizeof(file)` gives you the size of the variable `file`(which corresponds to the size of a pointer, i.e. 4 or 8 bytes), and not the size of the file itself.

You should check the return value of `ReadFile`

In the first part of the code you use a variable `Size` in the second part a variable `fileSize`. That doesn't look right. You certainly didn't assign the correct size to `fileSize` in the code you posted. Post complete compiling code please.

In addition you have a char size problem. If your program is compiled as unicode then `TChar` will become a wide-char(2 bytes). But you treat `TChar` as equivalent to a byte.

And you don't check the result of your malloc either. It'll be `null` if the file is too large.

Comment: You still have the potential widechar issue(are you compiling as Unicode or Ansi?) and You don't check the result of `ReadFile` or the content of `bytesRead`

Comment: The file encoding and the char type you compile with are completely independent. If you use `TChar` and assume it's 1 byte it won't work when compiling as unicode. And for UTF-16 encoded text files you'll need special treatment anyways.

Comment: I know that the file is read correctly (I can see in the debugger) , but how do I count the number of lines?