# Read file of ints and load it into array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have to open a file and read the numbers that are on it and then put these numbers in a array. I have the code below but it won't print me the numbers. I can't figure out why, can you guys help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{

    FILE *f;
    int *ptr;
    char inteiros[100];
    int inteiros_b[100];
    f=fopen("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Inteiros.txt", "r");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 0;   
    }
    else
        printf("Success\n");
    if(ptr==NULL);
        return NULL;
    while(fgets(inteiros, 100, f)!=NULL)
    {
        int i=0;
        inteiros_b[i]=atoi(inteiros);
        i++;    
    }
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("%d\n", inteiros_b[i]);



}
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: It is C. Why the uncertanty, is my code that bad? :|

Comment: It's not about that, but you have to add the `C` tag to your question

Comment: ok sorry about that, just edited. What about the code, where is my logic faulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fscanf` function

```
int main() {
    FILE * file = fopen("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Inteiros.txt", "r");
    int inteiros[100], i = 0, number;

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 0;
    } else printf("Success\n");
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", & number) > 0) {
        inteiros[i] = number;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    printf("%d\n", inteiros[i]);


}
```

Comment: Thanks i guess i should have used it that way i don't have to worry with the conversion from chart to int. If i wanted to use dynamic memory how would i implemment it in this example?

Comment: yes. i tried the code but the for loop still doesnt print me anything int main()
{

 FILE *f;
 int *ptr;
 int inteiros[100], number, i=0;
 f=fopen("C:\\Users\\PC\\Documents\\Inteiros.txt", "r");
 if(f==NULL)
 {
  printf("Error\n");
  return 0; 
 }
 else
  printf("Success\n");
 if(ptr==NULL);
  return NULL;
 while(fscanf(f, "%d", &number)>0)
 {
  inteiros[i]=number;
  i++;
 }
 fclose(f);
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
  printf("%d\n", inteiros[i]);
  

}

Comment: Correct this `& number` to `&number`

Comment: I did but it didnt do anything, Sorry for the mess above, i can't format it correctly. See the code here http://puu.sh/hl4zu/cabae1c129.png

Comment: I have only one intenger per line and like 80 lines

Comment: And you have to remove `if(ptr == NULL)`

Comment: That was the problem, now it prints numbers but it's also printing me trash after printing all the numbers in the text file.

Comment: Your `ptr` variable is unused and it equals `NULL` so your program stops always at this condition `if(ptr == NULL)` and returns `NULL`

Comment: That makes sense. So now i have problem with trash. fcanf is good the problem is in the for loop, right? What's the simplest way to get the number of elemments that it read in the file?

Comment: I added this line in the while loop if(fscanf(f, "%d", &number)==0)
   printf("%d numbers were read", i+1); but it's not printing in the output. I thought after its done fcanf would return 0. Does it not?

Comment: Use number of lines on the file and allocate `nblines * sizeof(integer)` using `malloc` or use a linked list

Comment: I shouldn't know how many lines it has. How do i allocate memory as it fills the array?

Comment: Here's how to count lines [count file lines number with C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139213/count-number-of-line-using-c)

Comment: It was easy as doing a printf of variable i after closing the file and then using that in the for loop as condition to stop. Well thanks a lot for the help. I will have to study dynamic memory now.

Answer (score 0):

if(ptr==NULL);
        return NULL;

You never assign ptr to anything, so wouldn't this code return NULL every time?

edit: also, should there be a semicolon after if(ptr==NULL)?

Comment: no. if you never initialize a variable before using it, you have undefined behaviour - anything ca happen.