# To count the total number of lines in a file using Unix system call in C

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am a beginner in C language and unix do not have much experience in it. I am trying to count total lines inside the file using unix system call but I am getting no result. My lineCount is always coming out as 0 I do not know why? I want someone to help me figure out the line count if possible.Thanks

```
int lineCount = 0;
while (*buffer != '\0') // to check the end of the file
{
    read( in_fd, buffer, BUFFERSZ);
    if (*buffer == '\n')
    {
       lineCount++;
    }
}

printf("Linecount: %i \n", lineCount );
```

Comment: unix system call? what?

Comment: @redFIVE Unix system Calls eg. open, read, close, lseek etc.

Comment: why not read *character by character* using `getch()` and increase `lineCount` when you encounter a `\n` :)

Comment: @CherubimAnand I have to complete this assignment using only Unix system calls no gets() or getc() can be used in it. I know how to count line using gets() but do not know how to do using Unix system Calls. Please see if you can help?

Comment: Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139213/count-number-of-line-using-c Use the code

Comment: @Twinkle Hi I am not allowed to use fgetc() method to count the line unfortunately. I have to use System Calls to help figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only checks `*buffer` for newlines, which is the first character of each `BUFFERSZ` chunk you read, i.e. your code doesn't even look at most of the input. (It also doesn't check for end-of-file correctly: you need to look at `read`'s return value for that.)

Here's a simple solution that emulates `fgetc` using `read`:

```
size_t lines = 0;
char c;
while (read(in_fd, &c, 1) == 1) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        lines++;
    }
}

printf("Linecount: %zu\n", lines);
```

---

If you can't use `printf` either, a quick workaround is:

```
static void print_n(size_t n) {
    if (n / 10) {
        print_n(n / 10);
    }
    char c = '0' + n % 10;
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

...
write(1, "Linecount: ", strlen("Linecount: "));
print_n(lines);
write(1, "\n", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with `open`, `read` and `write`, is really not much different from working with `fopen`, `fread`, and `fwrite` (or `fgets` and `fprintf`) aside from the burden of any *conversions, counting of bytes, and setting created file permission bits* being on you. When `write` writes a value such as `1020` to a file, it is writing the number of `bytes` you tell it to write, and the number will exist in the file in with the same *endianness* as your hardware uses.

For example if you have `unsigned v = 1020;` (`0x3fc` in hex) and then `write (fd, &v, sizeof v);`, when you look at your file with `hexdump` or `od` (or the like), it will contain `fc 03 00 00` (assuming your hardware is little-endian). Those are your `4-bytes` of an `unsigned` value `1020`. You can't open the file in a *text editor* and expect to see ASCII characters, because that isn't what was written to the file.

To find the number of lines in a file using `open` and `read`, you basically want to `open` the file, read the file into a buffer some reasonable number of bytes at a time and count the `'\n'` characters in the file.

(**note:** you will also want to check if the last character read from the file is something other than a `'\n'`. If it is you will want to add `+1` to your line-count to account for the non-POSIX line end of the final line.)

The only other caveat is to pay attention to the `mode` (permissions) for any newly created file you `open` for writing. Otherwise, you will find yourself without access to the newly created file. That is why open provides `mode_t mode` as the third argument in the case the `O_CREAT` flag is provided.

If you are going to stay true to only using `open, read, write` for your program I/O, then you will have to provide error message output to the terminal `STDERR_FILENO` in the event of an error. You may want a short helper function that will write *string* messages for that purpose.

Putting the pieces together, you could do something like the following while staying true to your cause. The following code takes the `infile` and `outfile` names as the first two arguments to the program, reads `infile` `65K bytes` at a time, counts the `'\n'`s in the file and then writes the result to `outfile` accounting for any non-POSIX line end for the file. `writeliteral` is provided as a helper for the error messages:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { BUFFERSZ = 1 << 16 };    /* 65K buffer size */

void writeliteral (int fildes, const char *s);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3) {
        writeliteral (STDERR_FILENO, "error: insufficient input.\n");
        writeliteral (STDERR_FILENO, "usage: progname infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[BUFFERSZ] = "";
    unsigned  i = 0, nlines = 0;
    ssize_t n = 0;
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
    int fd = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    if (fd == -1) {               /* validate file open for reading */
        writeliteral (STDERR_FILENO, "error: infile open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((n = read (fd, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)  /* read 65k chars */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)            /* count newlines in buf */
            if (buf[i] == '\n')
                nlines++;
    if (buf[i - 1] != '\n')       /* account for non-POSIX line end */
        nlines++;

    close (fd); /* close file */

    /* open outfile for writing, create if it doesn't exist */
    if ((fd = open (argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode)) == -1) {
        writeliteral (STDERR_FILENO, "error: outfile open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    write (fd, &nlines, sizeof nlines);  /* write nlines to outfile */

    close (fd); /* close file */

    return 0;
}

/** write a string literal to 'fildes' */
void writeliteral (int fildes, const char *s)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    const char *p = s;

    for (; *p; p++) {}
    count = p - s;

    write (fildes, s, count);
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ nl -ba ../dat/captnjack.txt
     1  This is a tale
     2  Of Captain Jack Sparrow
     3  A Pirate So Brave
     4  On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readwrite_lineno ../dat/captnjack.txt ../dat/jacklines.dat
$ hexdump -n 16 -C ../dat/jacklines.dat
00000000  04 00 00 00                                       |....|
00000004
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions. It shows you why you may appreciate the `printf` family of functions format specifiers even more when you are done.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail about the System calls.

Comment: Sure, glad to do it. Now, 'technically', the `open`, `read` and `write` calls are just libc functions. While they may have the same name as a Linux system call, the implementation in C is just that of a function. If you were programming in assembly -- then they would properly be called *system calls* which you would follow with a *system interrupt* to invoke them. They are properly referred to in C as your *lower-level* I/O functions. Good luck with your coding. If this answers your question, you can select the answer to indicate so, and help this question off the active list.

Answer (score -1):

Reference : [Count number of line using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139213/count-number-of-line-using-c) 
Use the code

```
FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.txt");
 int ch; 
int count=0;
 do { ch = fgetc(fp); 
if( ch== '\n')
 count++;
 }while( ch != EOF ); 
printf("Total number of lines %d\n",count);
```