# Read a CSV file into a dynamic array of structs C

Tags: arrays, c, csv, struct

I'm fairly new to C. I'm trying to read a `.CSV` file, then parse each line, then store the data in a dynamic array of pointers to structs. Unfortunately I've gone wrong somewhere in my implementation which is resulting in an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct dataSet {
    char ID;
    char postcode;
    int population;
    char contact;
    double x;
    double y;
}data;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char line[100] = "";
    int count = 0;
    int each = 0;
    data *allData = NULL;
    data *temp = NULL;

    FILE *file = fopen("dataset.csv", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! File null");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file))
    {
        if(NULL == (temp = realloc(allData, sizeof(*allData) * (count + 1))))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc problem\n");
            fclose(file);
            free(allData);
            return 0;
        }

        allData = temp;
        if (6 == scanf(line, "%s, %s, %d, %s, %lf, %lf",
                        &allData[count].ID,
                        &allData[count].postcode,
                        &allData[count].population,
                        &allData[count].contact,
                        &allData[count].x,
                        &allData[count].y)) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            printf("Problem with data\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (each = 0; each < count; each++)
    {
        printf("%s, %s, %d, %s, %lf, %lf\n",
        &allData[count].ID,
        &allData[count].postcode,
        &allData[count].population,
        &allData[count].contact,
        &allData[count].x,
        &allData[count].y);
    }

    free(allData);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `%s` format will read a *string*, and write a ***null-terminated** string* to the memory your pointer is pointing to. So even a one-letter string will need space for *two* characters to include the null-terminator. A single `char` variable will only fit a single character.

Comment: Also, after the reading-loop, the variable `count` will be the number of elements in the array you have allocated. But remember that this value will be *out of bounds* when used as an index. Think about this for the loop where you print the values (where you again need to think about *strings* versus *characters*).

Comment: sscanf() is not usable for non-trivial untrusted input. Instead, you could create a finite state machine. Also the realloc() scheme you use will lead to quadratic behavior.

Comment: Multiple `realloc` calls aren't really efficient, why not allocate **X** memory at the beginning and call `realloc` if you end up needing more?

Comment: Did you mean to use `sscanf` instead of `scanf`?

Comment: As @alex01011 said. Scan the whole file first to determine the size, and the do one single malloc.

Comment: And compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. The compiler is pretty good att pointing out flaws.

Comment: There are multiple problems with the presented code. Please construct a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Edit your question to show a small example (maybe 2 or three lines) of the input `.csv` file you want to read with this code.  (And I have edited your question to remove the request for books and tutorials ( and a few other edits.) to reduce the reasons to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for tips...

1 - your struct is wrong if your plan was to use dynamic memory.  The `char` members should be *pointers to char*, ( `char *` not `char` ) as shown below.  But to reduce complexity, use char arrays instead of forcing dynamic allocation for struct members:  i.e. do *not* use this:

```
typedef struct dataSet {
    char *ID;
    char *postcode;
    int population;
    char *contact;
    double x;
    double y;
}data;
```

Rather use this:

```
typedef struct dataSet {
    char ID[80];
    char postcode[11];
    int population;
    char contact[80];
    double x;
    double y;
}data;
```

If the lengths are not right, then make them bigger, but this will reduce calls to `calloc()` and `free()`.

2 - suggested steps:

- Count lines in file. (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139213/count-number-of-line-using-c)).  This will essentially open the file, count the lines and close the file.
- Use the count to allocate memory for that number of instances of `data` (i.e.  `data *records = malloc(sizeof(*records)*countOfLines);` )
- Open the file again.  If `file != NULL`, then...
- Begin to read file line by line in a loop, such as the `fgets(...)` loop you have.
- In this loop, suggest replacing `scanf()` with a series of calls to `strtok()` making the appropriate conversion one-by-one. Its a few more lines of code, but is easier in the long run to see what parsing problems you might run into.

The following pseudo code illustrates...

```
data *record = malloc(CountOfLines*sizeof(*record));
if(record)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file))
    {
        tok = strtok(line, ",");
        if(tok)
        { //convert string  
            strncpy(record[i].ID, tok, sizeof(record[i].ID) - 1);
            tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if(tok)
            {//convert string
                strncpy(record[i].postcode, tok, sizeof(record[i].postcode) - 1);
                tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
                if(tok)
                {//convert int
                    record[i].population = atoi(tok);
                    //and so on ...
```

Comment: `strtok()` is a terrible advice. You wont be able to read empty fields.

Comment: @wildplasser -  lines  can be vetted for minimum criteria (such as empty strings)  prior to calling `strtok`.  But as long as we are sharing opinions,  mine is that `scanf()` should be banished, it is an even poorer choice here.

Answer (score 1):

`[s]scanf()` is a nasty function. You don't have enough control once it fails. Problem is: there are too many conditions: the input can be incorrect, or the destination is not large enough. Even reading complete lines with `fgets()`, and parsing them afterwards, will only allow you to skip complete lines; also: the line buffer is mostly fixed sized, and `fgets()` could read incomplete lines. A way to keep complete control is to read character-based. This might imply a Finite State machine.

A simpler reader (using a *zero-state* machine) could be:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct omg {
        char o;
        int m;
        char g[11];
        };

struct wtf {
        unsigned size;
        unsigned used;
        struct omg *array;
        };

#define INITIAL_SIZE 7

struct wtf read_stuff(char *name)
{
FILE *fp;
unsigned icol,irec,len;
char buff[123];
struct wtf this = {0,0,NULL};

fp = fopen(name, "rb" );
if (!fp) return this;

for (icol=irec=len=0;   ; ) {
        int ch;
        if (this.used >= this.size) {
                size_t newsize;
                struct omg *tmp;

                newsize = this.size? this.size*2: INITIAL_SIZE;
                fprintf(stderr, "Realloc(%zu)\n", newsize);
                tmp = realloc(this.array, sizeof *this.array * newsize);
                this.array = tmp;
                this.size = newsize;
                }

        ch = getc(fp);
        switch(ch) {
        case '\r' : continue;

                /* End of field or record: terminate buffer */
#if 0
        case ',' :
#else
        case '\t' :
#endif

        case '\n' :
                buff[len] = 0;
                break;
        case EOF :
                goto done;

                /* Normal character: assign to buffer
                ** You may want to report too long fields here
                 */
        default:
                if (len >= sizeof buff -2) continue;
                buff[len++] = ch;
                continue;
                }

                /* When we arrive here, we have a new field. Let's process it ...*/
        switch (icol) {
        case 0: /* Assign first field here from buff[], (dont forget to check len!) */
                this.array[this.used].o = buff[0];
                break;

        case 1: /* Assign second field from buff[], this may need some additional checks
                ** You may want to avoid sscanf() here ...
                */
                sscanf(buff, "%d", &this.array[this.used].m );
                break;

        case 2: /* Assign third field from buff[] */
                if (len >= sizeof this.array[this.used].g)
                len = sizeof this.array[this.used].g -1;
                memcpy (this.array[this.used].g, buff, len);
                this.array[this.used].g[len] = 0;
                break;

        default: /* Ignore excess fields
                 ** You may want to report hem.
                 */
                break;
                }

                /* Do some bookkeeping */
        len = 0;
        if(ch == '\n') {
                /* You may want to check if icol==2, here */
                icol=0; irec++; this.used++;
                }
        else icol++;
        }
done:
fclose(fp);
        /* You could do a final realloc() here */

return this;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct wtf result;
unsigned idx;

result = read_stuff(argv[1] );
fprintf(stderr, "Result=%u/%u\n", result.used,result.size);

for (idx=0; idx < result.used; idx++) {
        printf("%c %d %s\n"
                , result.array[idx].o
                , result.array[idx].m
                , result.array[idx].g);
        if (idx >= 10) break;
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Posting this seconds after commenting negative advice under my answer is pretty rich.   Be honest, does either your comment or this answer really do anything to help answer the question?

Comment: I'd been editing for an hour and didn't want to spoil my effort. Besides: there are more ways to skin a cat. [my method focusses more on keeping in control]